# How to check storage class of existing key via Boto3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is there a way to obtain the storage class for a key in AWS Service (S3) using Python2.7 + Boto3?

I know that with Boto2 it was something like:

```
print key.storage_class
```

but I could not find something for obtain that with Boto3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
key = s3.Object('bucket_name','key')
print key.storage_class
```